# Python Tensorflow-GPU: "Successfully opened dynamic libraray cudart64_101.dll"

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am currently just trying to get tensorflow-gpu to work on my PC. When I run my script, consisting only of:

```py
import tensorflow
print("Test")
```

... then I get the output:

```
2020-04-24 18:16:53.660911: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_101.dll
Test

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Now, the code compiles just fine and exit code 0 should mean, that everything is alright. I am new to this entire thing, so forgive me if this is a stupid question, but is everything *really* alright? I am using the PyCharm IDE, and it prints the "2020-04-24 [...]" part in red, everything else is light-gray. Besides, it takes a few seconds to compile, even though all I am doing is importing tensorflow.

Red usually means error, and I find the compile time to be far too long. Is this normal?

And if not, how do I fix it?

Comment: When an error occurs tensorflow throws an `E` message. 
ex: E: ImportError: libcudnn.Version: cannot open shared object file. What you are seeing is just some semantic coloring by your IDE so you can better interpret the output.

Answer (score 0):

> is everything really alright?

Yes,everything is fine.

They are just the information message as they are prefixed with `I`, if it is the error message they would be prefixed with `E` or `W` for warnings are as shown below

```
2020-12-30 21:30:27.549172: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cupti64_101.dll

2020-12-30 21:30:27.599977: W tensorflow/core/framework/allocator.cc:101] Allocation of 37171200 exceeds 10% of system memory.

2021-12-30 21:30:27.704083: E tensorflow/core/profiler/internal/gpu/cupti_tracer.cc:1307] function cupti_interface_->Subscribe( &subscriber_, (CUpti_CallbackFunc)ApiCallback, this)failed with error CUPTI_ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_PRIVILEGES
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem , that's the only solution works with me:

1. check the folder path `C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages` . if any folder begins with `~`, delete it.
2. in the anaconda prompt run the following commands :

   ```sh
   conda remove tensorflow
   ```

   ```sh
   pip install tensorflow
   ```

   ```sh
   conda update --all
   ```