# Why is Tensorflow printing out a lot of things before printing out the desired output? Are there any problems it has said in the output?

Tags: python, tensorflow

Input:

```
import tensorflow as tf

rank1_tensor = tf.Variable(["Test"], tf.string) 
rank2_tensor = tf.Variable([["test", "ok"], ["test", "yes"]], tf.string)

print(tf.rank(rank2_tensor))
```

Output:

```
PS C:\Users\abhin\Machine Learning> conda activate Tensorflow
PS C:\Users\abhin\Machine Learning> & C:/Users/abhin/anaconda3/envs/Tensorflow/python.exe "c:/Users/abhin/Machine Learning/Machine Learning.py"
2021-06-04 12:13:12.064515: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_110.dll
2021-06-04 12:13:14.735677: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library nvcuda.dll
2021-06-04 12:13:14.796626: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1733] Found device 0 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0 name: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2060 computeCapability: 7.5
coreClock: 1.68GHz coreCount: 30 deviceMemorySize: 6.00GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 312.97GiB/s
2021-06-04 12:13:14.796755: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_110.dll 
2021-06-04 12:13:14.805459: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library cublas64_11.dll  
2021-06-04 12:13:14.805594: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library cublasLt64_11.dll
2021-06-04 12:13:14.809252: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library cufft64_10.dll   
2021-06-04 12:13:14.810573: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library curand64_10.dll
2021-06-04 12:13:14.819814: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library cusolver64_11.dll
2021-06-04 12:13:14.822758: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library cusparse64_11.dll
2021-06-04 12:13:14.823693: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library cudnn64_8.dll
2021-06-04 12:13:14.823908: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1871] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2021-06-04 12:13:14.824414: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX AVX2
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2021-06-04 12:13:14.825055: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1733] Found device 0 with properties:
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0 name: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2060 computeCapability: 7.5
coreClock: 1.68GHz coreCount: 30 deviceMemorySize: 6.00GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 312.97GiB/s
2021-06-04 12:13:14.825389: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1871] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2021-06-04 12:13:15.364158: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1258] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2021-06-04 12:13:15.364329: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1264]      0
2021-06-04 12:13:15.364590: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1277] 0:   N
2021-06-04 12:13:15.364894: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1418] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 3961 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2060, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 7.5)
tf.Tensor(2, shape=(), dtype=int32)
```

Comment: These are debugging log messages, they only provide useful information about your system. Refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35911252/disable-tensorflow-debugging-information) for how to disable them

Comment: @EhabIbrahim oh alright, thank you for telling me I was wondering for a long time

Comment: They are just the information message as they are prefixed with `I`, if it is the error message they would be prefixed with `E` or `W` for warnings.  For more information you can refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65580933/14290681).Thanks!